# Are mid-sentence exclamations archaic?

Tags: grammar

I've found when reading older literature written by Poe, Tolkien or Dickens that quite often in dialogue and description there will be an exclamation mid-sentence with the sentence continuing afterwards.
For example:

> Light grew, and lo! the Company passed through another gateway (...)
> (Lord of the Rings: RotK)

Also common in these books is alas! being mid sentence, with Dickens I recall there being a thank God! as well. Are these kinds of exclamations still used in modern writing or would they be considered archaic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I always need a capital letter after an exclamation mark?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/521457/do-i-always-need-a-capital-letter-after-an-exclamation-mark) Essentially, @Mike Graham implies that yes, such punctuation is archaic/literary, and that 'Light grew, and see, the Company passed through another gateway!' (with the exclamation mark in a less logical but tidier sentence-final position) would be more expected (if less accomplished) nowadays.

Comment: Interesting to think writings of Poe, Tolkien, or Dickens might be considered archaic. Probably indicates the reader's level of exposure to literature. In-sentence exclamations do suggest an earlier style, purple prose even. I'd say it's still a matter of taste.