# How many question marks and put where in this sentence? You should consider a memoir, Bob. How 'bout the end of all, or the road ahead

Tags: punctuation, syntactic-analysis, sentence

The sentence is

- How 'bout 'The End of All'Ø or 'The road ahead'Ø

where Ø is a stop or zero punctuation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a question mark mid-sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36821/using-a-question-mark-mid-sentence)

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities ([ref.](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2019/08/series-of-questions.html)).

- How 'bout "The end of all"? or "The road ahead"?
- How 'bout "The end of all", or "The road ahead"?

Comment: Why would we need a second question mark? Is the choice different from offering coffee or tea?

Comment: You've given a credible reference, which (similar / dissimilar) answers at the previous thread don't. The use of a sentence fragment is not much further away from totally acceptable norms, but I suppose OP indicates a single sentence.

Comment: @YosefBaskin As a "planned" question involving both coffe and tea I don't see the necessity of two question marks, but in the case of a second part which is a corrective (making up for what's suddenly seen as negligence, for instance), the lapse of time and changes in intonation seem to be no better rendered than by two question marks. I think that similar concerns are also valid for those suggestions for a memoir.