# A question about punctuations

Tags: punctuation

Can i say

> How can you even express “we don’t know anything”?, for you must think
> that we know at least one thing, namely, “we don’t know anything”.

Comment: Which part of the punctuation is causing you concern?

Comment: The "?," part. And should there be a "." after “we don’t know anything”?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a question mark mid-sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36821/using-a-question-mark-mid-sentence) See Jeremy Stein's answer; more modern writers probably tend to use workarounds.

Comment: To answer your question, better not.

Answer (score 1):

Using the question mark in mid-sentence is not generally acceptable. Here is one possible rewriting (I've taken some other minor liberties for style, but I hope you get the idea):

> How can one even express “we don’t know anything”, when one must think
> that we know at least one thing, namely, “we don’t know anything”?