# Do you always Capitalize after a question mark?

Tags: question-mark

I'm about to send out some questions to someone.

How was it starting your own business? tougher,easier than you had expected?

Does "tougher" need to become "Tougher"?

Comment: Also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25152/does-the-word-after-a-question-mark-start-with-a-capital-letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Any word after a question mark always needs to be capitalized.

Though in this case that makes a question and and incomplete thought. I'd rewrite it to:

> How was it starting your own business? Was it tougher or easier than you had expected?

Comment: Unless the question mark is in quotes and the following word is not: *"He where is my shoe?" demanded the old man. He could not find it.*