# Are dialogue tags after a question capitalized?

Tags: punctuation, capitalization, dialogue

When writing dialogue and dialogue tags, I have always asked myself if the tag is a complete sentence. If so, I use a comma and lower case such as:

> She said, "Bob."
> "Bob," she said.

"She said" isn't a full sentence on its own (in this context), so I use a comma instead of a period. I know this is correct. However, when it has either an exclamation mark (!) or a question mark (?), such as:

> "How are you doing?" she asked.

I use lower case for "she." Is this correct? Or should it be capitalized, since "How are you doing" ends with punctuation that is not a comma?

Comment: You're correct. "Where?" she asked. "No!" he yelled. In such cases these punctuation marks do *not* mark the end of a sentence,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the word after a question mark start with a capital letter?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25152/does-the-word-after-a-question-mark-start-with-a-capital-letter) User 1579 includes this case in their answer to the cited duplicate. Essentially, we don't have a comma variant of the question mark, so the original has also to serve where there would be a comma in non-interrogative speech before the dialogue tag. Similarly with the exclamation mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, everything above is correct as far as I'm concerned. But don't forget about these kinds of scenarios:

Like phrase A) "How are you doing?" she asked.

As opposed to B) "How are you doing?" She asked it like she already knew the answer.

Comment: @tchrist: Is it that 's' of 'she' in B) should only be in lower case? I too have this doubt.

Comment: No; the point was that it is a separate complete sentence and not an addition to the quote.

Comment: You have a choice with "How are you doing?" S/she asked as if she already knew the answer.