# When to capitalize (or not) the first letter in a question

Tags: questions, capitalization

Is it proper to capitalize the first letter in EVERY question or is it correct to NOT capitalize it when the question is preceded by a coma, colon, or semicolon within a sentence?

Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the word after a question mark start with a capital letter?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25152/does-the-word-after-a-question-mark-start-with-a-capital-letter)

Comment: Can you give some examples, please?

Answer (score 1):

You capitalise the first word of a *sentence*, whether it contains a question or not.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is it the title of a chapter?

After a comma or semicolon, does it seem right? (I think not.) After a colon, it depends on how formal the question ought to sound: Is it the title of a chapter? (In that case, it's not a bad idea to capitalize it, but it's not required.)